# What's the correct way to handle SQL connection pool cleanup and error handling in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb

I have been learning about using MySQL within Java using Oracle JDBC and I am trying to get into the mindset of try/catch and pool cleanup.

I am wondering if the following code is the correct way to perfectly clean everything up or if you notice holes in my code that requires something I've missed. For the record, I intend to use InnoDB and its row locking mechanism which is why I turn auto commit off.

```
try
{
    connection = getConnection(); // obtains Connection from a pool

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    // do mysql stuff here
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    if(connection != null)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.rollback(); // undo any changes
        }
        catch (SQLException e1)
        {
            this.trace(ExtensionLogLevel.ERROR, e1.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if(connection != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!connection.isClosed())
            {
                connection.close(); // free up Connection so others using the connection pool can make use of this object
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            this.trace(ExtensionLogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

`getConnection()` returns a Connection object from a pool and `connection.close()` closes it releasing it back to the pool *(so I've been told, still new to this so apologies if I am talking rubbish)*. Any help on any of this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: A well behaved connection pool implementation would do all the required clean up for you when you call `Connection.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not setting autocommit back to true in the finally block - your other threads that are relying on autocommit being set to true should not assume that the connections in the pool are in this state, but instead they should set autocommit to true before using a connection (just as this thread is setting autocommit to false).

In addition, you should check the connection's isClosed property before calling close() on it.

Other than that, I don't see any problems.